# Which capacitors can deliver the highest amount of current in short bursts

Tags: capacitor, high-current, electrolytic-capacitor

Ultra capacitors can store a huge amount of charge but can it discharge the fastest? In other words I am looking for a capacitor with the lowest internal resistance,also it should be at least in the microfarad range. 
Now the internal resistance varies with time for some caps, but in my case I would discharge it in a fraction of a second so it wouldn't probably matter if the internal resistance goes high after half a second or so.

I am also willing to build my own if such capacitors are not easily available commercially.

Comment: Please revise your question with measurable specifications in Joules, ns, us and ESR vs f.   Large C's do not have the lowest ESR as the ESR*C tends to be constant for any given family with variations with volume and voltage rating.  Thus decoupling caps need to be low ESL , and a wide variety if values. Such as e-cap, ceramic and plastic

Comment: Chat with Livermore National Labs, about their hand-constructed array of capacitors, used for GigaWatt laser pulse generation.

Comment: it depends a lot on those "fractions"  for microseconds low-esr electrolytics (and solid-aluminium) are probably OK, for nanoseconds film could work, especially low-inductance types,  MLCC are good to mid picoeconds,  but at low picoseconds everything is a combination of resistor, waveguide  inductor and capacitor.

Answer (score 1):

MLCC (multi-layer ceramic capacitors) have very low ESR and can handle tens of volts in the micofarad range.

Comment: Agree with this, just parallel and series many MLCC caps, this is the best and most popular method for crating cheap pulse rated capacitors.